# Error in deploying laravel project to shared server

Tags: php, laravel

I've a laravel project and I want to upload it to hostgator shared hosting server. I'm cloning the project in root directory and placing the public content in a folder in public_html.

I've updated the confiuration -

```
enter code here

require DIR . '/../../folder-name/bootstrap/autoload.php';
$app =        require_once DIR . '/../../folder-name/bootstrap/app.php';
```

but I'm getting 500 Internal Server Error.

Need expert advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

open public_html/index.php and set:

```
require DIR.'/../folder-name/bootstrap/autoload.php';

$app = require_once DIR.'/../folder-name/bootstrap/start.php';
```

and put this on top:

```
ini_set('eaccelerator.enable', 0);
```

and set permission to `storage` and `folder-name` dir